# Tabulating a final score for a questionnaire

Tags: vba, excel

Thanking in advance for your help with this one. I have searched everywhere but haven't been able to find an answer that addresses my issue.

Here is the background:

I have a questionnaire with 15 questions for which the possible answers are “Y”, “N” or “N/A”. For each question, I have assigned to the “Y” a value and to the “N” and “N/A” a zero.

I need a macro that will, for the active row in question, identify the heading of each question (1-15), look up each heading on a different worksheet in the same file, locate the number assigned to it if the answer is either “Y” or “N” (ignore the “N/A”s) and add all those numbers for the base score.

Then, as a second step, the macro will add only the “Y” answers and tabulate them against the base score for a final score.

For illustration purposes let’s say that I have the following questions:

```
    Table    Chair     Lamp     Plant
     Y         Y         N        N/A
```

In a different tab, the table looks like this:

```
     Table    Chair     Lamp     Plant
       5        10       8         15
```

I need a macro that will look at the column headings to match them, and then at the values assigned to table, chair and lamp (ignore plant since N/A), add them (for a total of 23). Then add only the Ys (for a total of 15) and then produce a final score of 65 (15 out of 23 or 65%).

Really stuck with this one… I have no idea how to even start… any help is truly appreciated.

Thank you so much!!!!

Marta

Comment: Try looking at the SUMIF function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a big task in front of you, you need to divide it up incrementally. Stack Overflow isn't here to write your macro for you.

The first part you want to do is match the column headers in the Active Row with the column headers on another worksheet, right? What I've posted below should get you the column headers on the question sheet and read them off to you. Try it out and take it further (do some googling if you need to). When you run into a problem with the code you make, that's where a question should be asked.

(Place this code into a fresh module in your workbook, and connect it to a button or something on the questionnaire worksheet)

```
Public Sub TallyQuestions()
    Dim questionSht As Worksheet
    Set questionSht = Sheets("Worksheet that has the questions you were talking about") 'replace name with name of questionSht

    Dim questionShtColHeaders As Range, cell As Range
    Set questionShtColHeaders = questionSht.Range("A1:A15")

    For Each cell In questionShtColHeaders
        MsgBox cell.Value
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: *When you have a big task in front of you, you need to divide it up incrementally. Stack Overflow isn't here to write your macro for you.* - Yet this is what you did :) How ironic :)

Comment: I'm leading her in the direction she needs to go so she can take the next step forward. If I just say that sentence, she still has nothing to go on (and my answer might get downvoted for being unhelpful lol).

Comment: Thank you. Of course you are right... I just felt a bit overwhelmed and had no idea where to start. Breaking it into small manageable pieces makes total sense and I thank you for both: for the suggestion and for getting me started with the whole thing.

Comment: I would also recommend considering INDEX/MATCH. It could easily solve this task, and would come with the added benefit of not needing a macro :).